# Where does the Jitsi Meet client software store the default server address?

Tags: windows-10, jitsi

I want to deploy a default server address for the [Jitsi Meet client software](https://desktop.jitsi.org/Main/Download.html). Does somebody know how and where it is stored?

Probably in the registry or in a configuration file in the profile... but I did not find it so far and did not find any documentation on that.

Comment: If you know the default value you can search the Windows registry and you can search through the files using a grep tool (I use PowerGREP but free alternatives are available) or `findstr /s text_to_find *`

Comment: https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart says that you'll be asked to fill in the server address during installation, so you may have to install it and fill that in in order to find where it is stored.

Comment: I can only find the address in some log files. It might be stored in one of the SQLite database files, like Cookies.